# Why does the formatting of PPTX files change when opened in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, microsoft-powerpoint

I am novice in ubuntu so my question may look very simple but as I am teacher I have to do lot of presentations. Unfortunately my all lectures which were in .pptx file format when opened in LibreOffice of Ubuntu the texts goes hayward up and down and slide looks unorganized. Also windows themes look very basic and unpleasant. So my question is that is there any way to make .pptx files open exactly the way they look in MS office 2007?
Your help would be truely appreciated..
Thank you.

Comment: I fear not. Had similar problems the other way round for my exams: Presentation written in LibreOffice odp, viewer was OpenOffice on Windows. Although both should use the same format, it was just ugly on Windows. Same if I tell LibreOffice to export as ppt or pptx. I don't know why, but for some reason presentations are not as portable as they should be. You can convert the presentation to PDF though. No animations ans effects there, but at least it looks exactly the same everywhere...

Comment: The question of which this is a duplicate of has been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer – no there isn't, and it will probably never be. The reason is both technical and political (hence e.g. the ongoing open document discussion at EU level), and is far to extensive to cover here. I can say this though: Microsoft's pptx, docx etc is also open standards, but in reality Microsoft is the only one who can make changes to it. You should either:

- Stick to the open format which LibreOffice supports much better(.odp)
- Use Office Online https://products.office.com/en-us/office-online/documents-spreadsheets-presentations-office-online

Comment: Thanks Wildcard.. Can i convert my .pptx files to .odp format successfully without changes found during conversion??

Comment: @G.Dubal No, it will not look the same as it would if you opened it with MS Powerpoint. It is two pretty different standards. However, LibreOffice will handle it much better if you convert it to odp, since it will render it much better.

Comment: Unfortunately, the situation is still the case today.  Formatting in PowerPoint is completely different from when I open it in Impress, even using ODP.  Are there better options that could be added to this answer?